# Ckfinder uploads the image but cant be inserted in the editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I have a CKEditor and CKFinder installed. I can upload the image using the finder. The image also shows up in the Browse section. When I select the image and insert it into the editor, a red cross shows up.
Think something is wrong with the path ? I have checked all the path and seems like everything is ok...

PS I can insert the thumbnail of the image in the editor...
any suggestions ???

Answer (score 1):

in the config file into ckfinder folder, the adress at the **"baseUrl ="** must point to the folder like this: http://www.yoursite.com/yourimagefolder/. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine with this.
In config.php:

```
'baseUrl'      => '/website/admin/ckfinder/userfiles/',
```

and not

```
'baseUrl'      => 'website/admin/ckfinder/userfiles/',
```

The '/' at beginning...